# WordPress Load Only Page Text

Tags: theme-development, pages, the-content, get-the-title

I'm working on a page template and I need `the_title` to be separate from the page text. I'm not sure how to load `the_content` without it having the title.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `the_content()` doesn't contain the title, unless a plugin or theme is programmatically inserting it into the content. By default `the_content()` only displays the post content.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );// puts the title in h3 tags

      the_content(); // adds the content
      endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Notice that you can use the title function where you want as long as it is after the if/while/the_post and before the endwhile;  This is how you retrieve the title and the content in separate areas.  I can't comment on this part of stackexchange, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that you have a function or a plugin that is inserting into your content the title.

To check if that's right, try to use `get_the_content()`, it's a function that does not pass the content through the `the_content()`(important: `get_the_content()` will not expand shortcodes)

Answer (score 0):

The following code only load the content of page template

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content(); // show the content
    endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```